# How do I update the -data-row attribute inside a modal launched with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal that is launched like this:

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="edit_item" data-row="6">
 <i class="icon-open"></i>
</a>
```

Which then in return fires

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".edit_item", function() {

        var row=$(this).data("row");
        var params="myfile.php&link="+row;
        open_box_edit(params);
});
```

The `open_box_edit` is just:

```
function open_box_edit(params)
{        

      var URL=ajax_url+"/?"+params;
      var modal = $('#modal_edit');
        modal
            .find('.modal-body')
            .load(URL, function (responseText, textStatus) {
                if ( textStatus === 'success' || 
                     textStatus === 'notmodified') 
                {
                    modal.modal("show");
                }
        });  
}
```

Everything works correctly inside `modal-body`, but now I have added a `modal-footer` div to that modal and inside that div is a link to delete an item, which has the same `data-row` attribute as the opened modal. Basically:

```
<div id="modal_edit" class="modal fade" 
     tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="plan-info-edit" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- CONTENT HERE -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">

            <!-- DELETE BUTTON -->
            <a href="javascript:;" class="delete_item" data-row="">
              <i class="icon-delete"></i>
            </a>
            <!-- DELETE BUTTON -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I do it so that the `<a href="javascript:;" class="delete_item" data-row="">` essentially becomes `<a href="javascript:;" class="delete_item" data-row="6">`? Basically all I need to do is update the data-row of delete_item class inside the modal.

Any hints are greatly appreciated!

UPDATE 1:

- I am thinking possibly giving `open_box_edit` another parameter (the row) and then in the function run something like `$('.delete_item').data('row', row);`. But how do I target that specific div and modal-footer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the data attribute when edit item is clicked.

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".edit_item", function() {
    var row=$(this).data("row");
    $('.delete_item').data("row",row); // add this line
    var params="myfile.php&link="+row;
    open_box_edit(params);
});
```

Comment: That was the perfect solution and the one that instantly worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
.load(URL, function (responseText, textStatus) {
                if ( textStatus === 'success' || 
                     textStatus === 'notmodified') 
                {
                    $('div.modal-footer > a.delete_item').data('row', param);
                    modal.modal("show");
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var val=6;
var footerDataRow=$(".modal-footer").find('a');
footerDataRow.data('data-row',val);
```

This can be done in one line, I have dissected it so that you understand it.